# Magento2.3 - Can't Import product CSV file

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, importexport

I can't import `CSV` file. Got error **https://prnt.sc/u0e9tr**

```
Data validation failed. Please fix the following errors and upload the file again.
Number of columns does not correspond to the number of rows in the header in row(s): 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52

Checked rows: 52, checked entities: 52, invalid rows: 52, total errors: 52
```

CSV file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nvkVjHkydxOA3Y128Hyw1MxOFTzxDGfl/view?usp=sharing

Comment: CSV file is not accessible. Please make it readable to everyone so one can check and help you.

Comment: CSV File: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wY6JvHZWmcGj1oduJUrF5SqhZ8-psOJUCX2r8VeR1e4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: It's asking for permission. Not able to view it.

Comment: I updated https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nvkVjHkydxOA3Y128Hyw1MxOFTzxDGfl/view?usp=sharinghttps://drive.google.com/file/d/1nvkVjHkydxOA3Y128Hyw1MxOFTzxDGfl/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The file is not in the correct format. Column `SKU` contains all the values and other columns are empty. Please correct the file and try to import it again.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in your comma-separated CSV format. SKU column and description have multiple commas so columns are not according to data and it gives an error.

Also, I see the column you set is not according to default Magento. To check this just export 1 product from the system and compare it with your CSV format. you will see many issues and just fix them by correcting data. try to check only for 2 rows of data.

Hope it helps